# Nao consigo fazer uma ListView

Tags: react-native

Galera, sou nove com React-Native e estou tendo dificuldades em entender a LisView.  Nao consigo entender como consigo criar varias delas usando o 'for'. 
fiz isso ate agora.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { AppRegistry, ListView, View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

// Row data (hard-coded)
const rows = [
  {id: 0, text: 'View'},
  {id: 1, text: 'Text'},
  {id: 2, text: 'Image'},
  {id: 3, text: 'ScrollView'},
  {id: 4, text: 'ListView'},
]

// Row comparison function
const rowHasChanged = (r1, r2) => r1.id !== r2.id

// DataSource template object
const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged})

class list extends Component {
  // Initialize the hardcoded data
  state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(rows)
    }

    renderRow = (rowData) => {
      return (
        <Text style={styles.row}>
          {rowData.text}
        </Text>
      )
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <ListView
          style={styles.container}
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderRow}
        />
      )
    }
  }

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
    },
    row: {
      padding: 15,
      marginBottom: 5,
      backgroundColor: 'skyblue',
    },
  })
// App registration and rendering
AppRegistry.registerComponent('list', () => list);
```

Comment: Aparece algum erro?

Comment: Na verdade eh inexperiencia mesmo. consegui fazer uma lista simples mas gostaria de introzir um for para que possam tem varias.